# storing length of a list in a different list in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

here is a (3,3) list:

```
Names = [['ayushi','bhumi','aman'],['aakriti','ankur','saxena'],['preeti','chhavi','vicky']]
```

I want to store length of each element in a different (3,3) list .
 I have used below code for this:

```
length=[]

for i in Names:

    for j in i:

        length.append(len(j))
```

but i am getting below output:

```
[6, 5, 4, 7, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5]
```

whereas desired output is:

```
654

756

665
```

how can i do this and do tell me if there exist an inbuilt function for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following list comprehension:

```
length = [''.join([str(len(i)) for i in l]) for l in Names]
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> length
['654', '756', '665']
```

You can convert this to `int` after using `map` if that's what you need:

```
>>> list(map(int, length))
[654, 756, 665]
```

If I misunderstood your question, and instead you want a list of 3 lists, then you can do:

```
length = [[len(i) for i in l] for l in Names]

>>> length
[[6, 5, 4], [7, 5, 6], [6, 6, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Names = [['ayushi','bhumi','aman'],['aakriti','ankur','saxena'],['preeti','chhavi','vicky']]

length=[]
for i in Names:
    str_len_list = []
    for j in i:
        str_len_list.append(str(len(j)))
    length.append(''.join(str_len_list))
```

Comment: what is the purpose of ''.join(str_len_list)..why have you used it

Comment: used to join sequence of string by string separator, here the separator is empty string ('')